# JSON-RPC Errors On Certain Domains Only?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

Does anyone know if MetaMask rejects requests from certain domain extensions, such as {domain}.xyz ?

We are interacting with a Smart Contract just to send a simple transaction. It works on 3 different sites without issue. However, a forth site with the same code does not work.

The 4th site is hosted somewhere else, but has an SSL certificate. It also seems to happen primarily on the Fantom Network.

I've verified the contract code, added the Fantom Network to MetaMask various ways and tried different RPC urls, etc.

No matter what we try, it won't work on a specific domain name, but works fine on others.

Any ideas?